# Retrieve XML data using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm having a hard time retrieving below xml data separately using PHP.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <document>
       <data>
          <headertext>Welcome</headerp>
          <postheadertext>Travellers</headers>
       </data>
    </document>
```

This is the php code written to retrieve the xml data & this doesn't work.

```
<a id="titleyellow">
<?php$xml=simplexml_load_file("storeddata.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");echo $xml->headertext;?>
</a>

<a id="titlewhite">
<?php$xml=simplexml_load_file("storeddata.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");echo $xml->postheadertext;?>
</a>
```

The xml data should be as it is & i am looking for a code that could retrieve this data to display seperately within HTML content.

I Really appreciate whoever can assist me with this. Thanks heaps!

Best regards
David

Comment: My bad,

The XML file should be:
<document>
       <data>
          <headertext>Welcome</headertext>
          <postheadertext>Travellers</postheadertext>
      </data>
</document>

Answer (score 2):

It's `$xml->data->headertext` and `$xml->data->postheadertext` obviously. There is a `<data>` element before the header elements. Not sure why you think you can omit that.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php again

Comment: Cheers mate! You made my day!!!

I am a newbie but too much of a barnacle to find that out.

Have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

When you load the xml file using the php `simplexml_load_file` function to a variable. The veritable becomes an object.

```
<?php 
$xml=simplexml_load_file("storeddata.xml");
?>
```

So, in your case, the `$xml` variable becomes a multi-level object where every elements of xml file are key of the object.

To access the data of the element, need to call like this bellow code.

```
echo $xml->data->headertext . "<br>";
```

Here,
`data` is the key of `$xml` object.
`headertext` is the key of `data`.

The output will be the value of `headertext` = **Welcome**